# How can customize boders for a UIButton using UIBuilder and Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have [these buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXizv.png), and because both buttons have rounded corners you can see a small gap between them at their aligned corners. I want the top button to have rounded corners on the top and the bottom button to have rounded corners at the bottom, giving the illusion of one big button divided in half.

Is it possible to have a `UIButton` that has round corners on the top and normal corners on the bottom? I am using XCode 7.

Thanks!

Comment: you can set only top left and top right corner radiuses - programmatically, it's easy. If you want, I can share with extension

Comment: what do you mean with extension?

Comment: Can you show me the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this extension:

```
your_class {
    ...
}

extension UIButton {
    override func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
your_button.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 10)
```